# MongoDB Slice set of documents

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I want to get the nth position of a given collection.
However, all the `slice` methods I find, all refer to a given array in the document schema. In this case, I want to get the nth document of the collection. I tried `$`, but it gives me a syntax error:

```
result = await db.collection(col_name).find(
    { projection: { $: { $slice: [0, nPosition] } } }
).sort({ timestamp: -1 }).toArray();
```

Any clue how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `limit` and `skip` :

```
result = await db.collection(col_name).find().sort({ timestamp: -1 }).skip(nPosition).limit(1).toArray();
```